# How to access read-only (static const) data of shared library from C/C++ program with known OFFSET

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, libgcrypt

I have installed libgcrypt shared library. libgcrypt.so file is generated .
It has some read-only data.

```
./configure   ( without -g option for debug symbol)
make install 


static const u32 encT[256] =
  {
    0xa56363c6, 0x847c7cf8, 0x997777ee, 0x8d7b7bf6,
    0x0df2f2ff, 0xbd6b6bd6, 0xb16f6fde, 0x54c5c591,
    0x50303060, 0x03010102, 0xa96767ce, 0x7d2b2b56,
...

}

static const struct
{
  u32 T[256];
  byte inv_sbox[256];
} dec_tables =
  {
    {
      0x50a7f451, 0x5365417e, 0xc3a4171a, 0x965e273a,
      0xcb6bab3b, 0xf1459d1f, 0xab58faac, 0x9303e34b,
      0x55fa3020, 0xf66d76ad, 0x9176cc88, 0x254c02f5,
      .....},

    {
      0x52,0x09,0x6a,0xd5,0x30,0x36,0xa5,0x38,
      0xbf,0x40,0xa3,0x9e,0x81,0xf3,0xd7,0xfb,
      0x7c,0xe3,0x39,0x82,0x9b,0x2f,0xff,0x87,
      .....
    }  
 }
```

Using nm command I am able to find the offset of read-only data.

```
nm /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep encT
0008ffc0 r encT

nm /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so | grep dec_tables
0008fac0 r dec_tables
```

I want to access those read-only data from C/C++ program.

```
    //sample.c
    // gcc sample.c -lgcrypt 

    #include <gcrypt.h>

    int main()
    {

    // ADDRESS of encT[0] = ? + OFFSET  (0008ffc0)
    //print value of encT[0] as 0xa56363c6
    // ADDRESS of dec_tables.T[0] = ? + OFFSET (0008fac0)
    //print value of dec_tables.T[0] as 0x50a7f451
    //print value of dec_tables.inv_sbox[0] as 0x52

    }
```

I have following questions

1. How to use those offset to access those read-only data (encT,
   dec_tables.T,dec_tables.inv_sbox)  from C program ?

   **2. Is there any other way to find the ADDRESS of encT, dec_tables.T,dec_tables.inv_sbox ?**

EDIT-1 :
global(extern) function, gcry_cipher_decrypt()  is used to perform decryption and it calls static do_decrypt --> static do_decrypt_fn() which uses dec_tables.T,dec_tables.inv_sbox. So it is possible to find ADDRESS of dec_tables.T,dec_tables.inv_sbox with respect to address of 
gcry_cipher_decrypt ?

I am using gcc-4.9, Ubuntu 16.04.

It will be a great help if someone help me to complete the above sample program or any link to understand how I can do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can code not use `static` in the data definitions?

Comment: If it is `static`, the author's idea was that it should not be directly accessed by other modules.

Comment: @chux, inside the libgcrypt library , static function inside other source file are using these (i.e. encT) static data.

Comment: I want to access those static data from other independent C program (not part of library). As the static data section are located/loaded at fixed OFFSET, we may access those data with respect to address of some function.

Comment: Can't you just copy the definitions? They're const anyway and won't change.

Comment: @BjornA., no I want to access static data of shared library. so by simply copying is not  a solution.